# How can I draw a rectangle on webpage using asp.net with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, draw

Is it possible to draw shapes, lines, and other graphical objects on a website form in C#

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your question! However, this is not really the kind of question that Stack Overflow is here to answer. [Read this for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) Once you have a specific question about a specific problem you are having with code you are writing, feel free to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="image/jpeg" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing.Text" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing.Imaging" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing.Drawing2D" %>

<%

Response.Clear();
int height = 100;
int width = 200;
Random r = new Random();
int x = r.Next(75);

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
g.Clear(Color.Orange);
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, 1, 1, width-3, height-3);
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, 2, 2, width-3, height-3);
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, width, height);
g.DrawString("The Code Project", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Italic), 
SystemBrushes.WindowText, new PointF(x,50) );

bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
g.Dispose();
bmp.Dispose();
Response.End();

%>
```

Source:

[Source drawing Web Graphics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1827/Web-Graphics-On-The-Fly-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: thanks sir , but sir here you used bitmap but i don't want to use bitmap image , i need to draw a simple rectangle in webpage.aspx , will you pleas tell me another way, and this is working but sir i do not need image. thanks in advance

Comment: can anybody help me , i don't want to use bitmap as in above answer.

Comment: @KaushalJoshi If you don't want to do the above, why did you accept it as the answer? (It *is* the answer, by the way, but your comment is very confusing)

Comment: @Andrew Barber,i accepted your answer because according to question it is correct but  sir can you draw rectangle without bitmap image. i Don't want to use Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);. means i need rectangle on web page without image. page should be free from images

Comment: @KaushalJoshi It's not actually my answer, but how would you propose to draw without an image to draw on?

Comment: I think you need to use a bitmap, or something like to draw on first, I don't know another method for it, except for the answer @Naresh Pansuriya is giving.

Answer (score 7):

This will draw rectangle in simple html..

```
<div style="width:500px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;">This is a rectangle!</div>
```

If you want draw in HTML5 then please follow url [Ractangle in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)

Comment: thanks sir , but i want to make a web page (using asp.net c#) in which i need a rectangle of any dimension using c# coding. please help me sir , thanks in advance